# How to get Node IP range in Kubenetes for MetallB Config file

Tags: kubernetes, metallb

I am having 1 Master node and 1 worker node in K8s on premises cluster. Node Ip are `10.128.0.4` &  `10.128.0.5`

```
NAME         STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION    INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION                CONTAINER-RUNTIME
learning-1   Ready    control-plane,master   43h   v1.23.12   10.128.0.4    <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64   docker://20.10.21
learning-2   Ready    <none>                 43h   v1.23.12   10.138.0.5    <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64   docker://20.10.21
```

I am using MetallB to get external IP's. The config file is below: I provide Node Ip range in below file. I want to confirm whether it's correct or not?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 10.128.0.4 - 10.128.0.5 #Update this with your Nodes IP range
```

The `svc` is assigned with `External IP` as `10.128.0.4`.

Logs:

```
[root@learning-1 ss_kubernetese]# kubectl get svc
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes            ClusterIP      10.96.0.1     <none>        443/TCP          43h
svc-sdb-cluster       ClusterIP      None          <none>        3306/TCP         93m
svc-sdb-cluster-ddl   LoadBalancer   10.96.30.94   10.128.0.4    3306:30720/TCP   93m
```

Ref link: [metallb load balancer ip address range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64231293/metallb-load-balancer-ip-address-range)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no problem, probably caused by the extra spaces in `10.128.0.4-10.128.0.5`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 10.128.0.4-10.128.0.5
```